# Como corrigir estes Erros no PHP: Notice: Undefined - Deprecated

Tags: php

Tudo bom?
Eu sei que vai parecer pergunta duplicada. Mas infelizmente as respostas das outras perguntas não me ajudou muito. Estou mexendo em um script pronto que peguei na internet e estou tentando corrigir os erros que coloquei para exibi-los.

> **Erros que aparece no checklogin.php:**
>
> Notice: Undefined index: cfgProgDir in /home/USER/public_html/admin/protecao/checklogin.php on line 57
>
> Notice: Undefined index: entered_login in /home/USER/public_html/admin/protecao/checklogin.php on line 63
>
> Notice: Undefined index: entered_password in /home/USER/public_html/admin/protecao/checklogin.php on line 64
>
> Deprecated: mysql() [function.mysql]: This function is deprecated; use mysql_query() instead in
>   /home/USER/public_html/admin/protecao/checklogin.php on line 143
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: dbOld in /home/USER/public_html/admin/protecao/checklogin.php on line 246
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: messageOld in /home/USER/public_html/admin/protecao/checklogin.php on line 247

**Código de fonte do checklogin.php** as linhas que estão com erro, comentei com **// LINHA**

```
<?PHP
    // loading functions and libraries
    function random($max) {
        // create random number between 0 and $max
        srand( (double)microtime() * 1000000 );
        $r = round(rand(0, $max));
        if ($r != 0) $r = $r - 1;
        return $r;
    }

    function rotateBg() {
        // rotate background login interface
        global $backgrounds, $bgImage, $i;
        $c = count($backgrounds);
        if ($c == 0) return;
        $r = random($c);
        if ($backgrounds[$r] == '' && $i < 10) {
            $i++;
            rotateBg();
        } elseif ($i >= 10) {
            if (!$bgImage || $bgImage == '') {
                $bgImage = 'bg_lock.gif';
            } else {
                $bgImage = $bgImage;
        }   }
        else { $bgImage = $backgrounds[$r]; }
        return $bgImage;
    }

    function in_array_php3($needle, $haystack) {
        // check if the value of $needle exist in array $haystack
        // works for both php3 and php4
        if ($needle && $haystack) {
            if (phpversion() >= 4) {
                // phpversion = 4
                return(in_array($needle, $haystack));
            } else {
                // phpversion = 3
                for ($i = 0; $i <= count($haystack); $i++) {
                    if ($haystack[$i] == $needle) {
                        return(true);
                }   }
                return(false);
        }   }
        else return(false);
    }

    if ($noDetailedMessages == true) {
        $strUserNotExist = $strUserNotAllowed = $strPwNotFound = $strPwFalse = $strNoPassword = $strNoAccess;
    }
    if ($bgRotate == true) {
        $i = 0;
        $bgImage = rotateBg();
    }

    // Check if secure.php has been loaded correctly
    if ( !defined("LOADED_PROPERLY") || $HTTP_GET_VARS['cfgProgDir'] || $HTTP_POST_VARS['cfgProgDir']) { // LINHA 57
        echo "Parsing of phpSecurePages has been halted!";
        exit();
    }

    // make post variables global
    $entered_login = $HTTP_POST_VARS['entered_login']; // LINHA 63
    $entered_password = $HTTP_POST_VARS['entered_password']; // LINHA 64

    // check if login is necesary
    if (!$entered_login && !$entered_password) {
        // use data from session
        if (phpversion() >= 4) {
            // phpversion = 4
            session_start();
            // session hack to make sessions on old php4 versions work
            if (phpversion() > 4.0) {
                $login = $HTTP_SESSION_VARS['login'];
                $password = $HTTP_SESSION_VARS['password'];
            }
        } else {
            // phpversion = 3
            session_start_php3();
    }   }
    else {
        // use entered data
        if (phpversion() >= 4) {
            // phpversion = 4
            session_start();
            session_unregister("login");
            session_unregister("password");

            // encrypt entered login & password
            $login = $entered_login;
            if ($passwordEncryptedWithMD5 && function_exists(md5)) {
                $password = md5($entered_password);
            } else {
                $password = $entered_password;
            }
            // session hack to make sessions on old php4 versions work
            if (phpversion() > 4.0) {
                $HTTP_SESSION_VARS['login'] = $login;
                $HTTP_SESSION_VARS['password'] = $password;
            } else {
                session_register("login");
                session_register("password");
            }
        } else {
            // phpversion = 3
            session_destroy_php3();
            session_start_php3();

            // encrypt entered login & password
            $login = $entered_login;
            if ($passwordEncryptedWithMD5 && function_exists(md5)) {
                $password = md5($entered_password);
            } else {
                $password = $entered_password;
            }
            session_register_php3("login", "STRING", $login);
            session_register_php3("password", "STRING", $password);
    }   }

    if (!$login) {
        // no login available
        include($cfgProgDir . "interface.php");
        exit;
    }
    if (!$password) {
        // no password available
        $message = $strNoPassword;
        include($cfgProgDir . "interface.php");
        exit;
    }


    // use phpSecurePages with Database
    if ($useDatabase == true) {
        // contact database
        if ( empty($cfgServerPort) ) {
            mysql_connect($cfgServerHost, $cfgServerUser, $cfgServerPassword)
            or die($strNoConnection);
        } else {
            mysql_connect($cfgServerHost . ":" . $cfgServerPort, $cfgServerUser, $cfgServerPassword)
            or die($strNoConnection);
        }
        $userQuery = mysql($cfgDbDatabase, "SELECT * FROM $cfgDbTableUsers WHERE status='S' AND $cfgDbLoginfield = '$login'") // LINHA 143
            or die($strNoDatabase);

        // check user and password
        if (mysql_num_rows($userQuery) != 0) {
            // user exist --> continue
            $userArray = mysql_fetch_array($userQuery);

            if ($login != $userArray[$cfgDbLoginfield]) {
                // Case sensative user not present in database
                $message = $strUserNotExist;
    //          include($cfgProgDir . "logout.php");
                include($cfgProgDir . "interface.php");
                exit;
        }   }
        else {
            // user not present in database
            $message = $strUserNotExist;
    //      include($cfgProgDir . "logout.php");
            include($cfgProgDir . "interface.php");
            exit;
        }
        if (!$userArray[$cfgDbPasswordfield]) {
            // password not present in database for this user
            $message = $strPwNotFound;
            include($cfgProgDir . "interface.php");
            exit;
        }
        if (stripslashes($userArray["$cfgDbPasswordfield"]) != $password) {
            // password is wrong
            $message = $strPwFalse;
    //      include($cfgProgDir . "logout.php");
            include($cfgProgDir . "interface.php");
            exit;
        }
        if ( isset($userArray["$cfgDbUserLevelfield"]) && !empty($cfgDbUserLevelfield) ) {
            $userLevel = stripslashes($userArray["$cfgDbUserLevelfield"]);
        }
        if ( ( $requiredUserLevel && !empty($requiredUserLevel[0]) ) || $minUserLevel ) {
            // check for required user level and minimum user level
            if ( !isset($userArray["$cfgDbUserLevelfield"]) ) {
                // check if column (as entered in the configuration file) exist in database
                $message = $strNoUserLevelColumn;
                include($cfgProgDir . "interface.php");
                exit;
            }
            if ( empty($cfgDbUserLevelfield) || ( !in_array_php3($userLevel, $requiredUserLevel) && ( !isset($minUserLevel) || empty($minUserLevel) || $userLevel < $minUserLevel ) ) ) {
                // this user does not have the required user level
                $message = $strUserNotAllowed;
                include($cfgProgDir . "interface.php");
                exit;
        }   }
        if ( isset($userArray["$cfgDbUserIDfield"]) && !empty($cfgDbUserIDfield) ) {
            $ID = stripslashes($userArray["$cfgDbUserIDfield"]);
    }   }


    // use phpSecurePages with Data
    elseif ($useData == true && $useDatabase != true) {
        $numLogin = count($cfgLogin);
        $userFound = false;
        // check all the data input
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $numLogin; $i++) {
            if ($cfgLogin[$i] != '' && $cfgLogin[$i] == $login) {
                // user found --> check password
                if ($cfgPassword[$i] == '' || $cfgPassword[$i] != $password) {
                    // password is wrong
                    $message = $strPwFalse;
                    include($cfgProgDir . "logout.php");
                    include($cfgProgDir . "interface.php");
                    exit;
                }
                $userFound = true;
                $userNr = $i;
        }   }
        if ($userFound == false) {
            // user is wrong
            $message = $strUserNotExist;
            include($cfgProgDir . "logout.php");
            include($cfgProgDir . "interface.php");
            exit;
        }
        $userLevel = $cfgUserLevel[$userNr];
        if ( ( $requiredUserLevel && !empty($requiredUserLevel[0]) ) || $minUserLevel ) {
            // check for required user level and minimum user level
            if ( !in_array_php3($userLevel, $requiredUserLevel) && ( !isset($minUserLevel) || empty($minUserLevel) || $userLevel < $minUserLevel ) ) {
                // this user does not have the required user level
                $message = $strUserNotAllowed;
                include($cfgProgDir . "interface.php");
                exit;
        }   }   
        $ID = $cfgUserID[$userNr];
    }


    // neither of the two data inputs was chosen
    else {
        $message = $strNoDataMethod;
        include($cfgProgDir . "interface.php");
        exit;
    }

    // restore values
    if ($dbOld) $db = $dbOld; // LINHA 246
    if ($messageOld) $message = $messageOld; // LINHA 247
    ?>
```

Peço desculpa pelo tamanho do código. mas por motivo de todas as pesquisas que fiz eu não conseguir acertar essas linhas. Se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei muito agradecido.

Comment: Esse código foi escrito em um momento de transição do php3 para o php4, tem até uma implementação de `in_array()` nem sei se vale apena corrigir ele. Tem várias perguntas de como resolver undefined index/variable e de como conveter código `mysql_` para `mysqli_` ou PDO.

Comment: Particularmente acho que este código está extremamente obsoleto (isso: `phpversion() >= 4` é a maior prova!). O primeiro erro é porque não existe os parâmetros necessário (ou seja, o link não tem `?cfgProgDir=XXx&entered_login=YYYY`. Dai começa mais uma coisa: o `$HTTP_GET_VARS` já é considerado, há muito tempo, obsoleto, sendo "substituído" pelo `$_GET`. Depois o `mysql()` já está obsoleto, o substituto é o `mysql_query()`, como diz no erro, porém ele também já era, então migre para o `mysqli_query()`.  Os últimos dois erros é porque a variável não existe mesmo. Você deve usar `isset()`.

Answer (score 0):

Esse tipo de erro ocorre quando você tenta acessar uma variável que pode não estar setada.

Há várias maneiras de validar isso ou você pode usar o isset, ou então colocar uma @ antes da mesma para fazer o ignore.

> Exemplo isset com if ternário

```
<?php
//if ternario. isset retora true ou false ? indica que você finalizou a condição logica o valor antes do : quer dizer se a expressão for true (verdade) e o valor depois quer dizer se o valor for false (falso).
$cfgProgDir = isset($cfgProgDir) ? $cfgProgDir : "valor_padrao";
echo $cfgProgDir;
```

> Exemplo com @

```
<?php
//O @ ignora o erro nessa linha, porém não sei se é recomendado o uso do mesmo.
echo @$cfgProgDir;
```

Obs: verifique se não existe outra alternativa, esse código está obsoleto. Vai te dar trabalho com servidores que contenham php mais recentes.